# Use NPM Packages with SAPUI5 Typescript

Tags: typescript, sapui5, ui5-tooling

I am trying to use the npm-package `soap` in my SAPUI5 APP.

I am new to web development, so I tried to follow this tutorial:
https://github.com/SAP-samples/ui5-typescript-tutorial/tree/main/exercises/ex8

What I have tried:

- Created an SAPUI5-project with `yeoman-generator easy-ui5 ts-app`
- Installed `soap` as a development dependency
- Tried to import the `createClient` method into a controller:
  `import { createClient } from "soap"`
- Create a client:
  `const SOAPClient:any = createClient("",function(){});`
- Run the app with `npm start`

But I get errors like this in chrome console:

> *GET http://</resources/http.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) `loadScript` @ ui5loader.js:1351 2022-05-24 10:39:01.476100 failed to
> load JavaScript resource: http.js -  `sap.ui.ModuleSystem`
> Log.js?eval:452*

In the terminal I get messages like:

> *preferring built-in module `http` over local alternative at `/home/user/projects/zvtle.om/node_modules/string_decoder/lib/http.js`,
> pass `preferBuiltins: false` to disable this behavior or
> `preferBuiltins: true` to disable this warning*

In Chrome under sources then resources I can see that the UI5 libraries are loaded, and a **soap.js** file that has been parsed and now uses `sap.ui.definde`. However, all of the packages that `soap` would require (such as `http`) are not loaded.

I have searched a long time and did not find where I could parse `preferBuiltins: true` as mentioned in the terminal output and I am not even sure if that would fix my problems.

Comment: I'm not sure and I can't try, but since it seems to be a typescript import error, perhaps this is a flag that needs to be set in the compiler options of tsconfig.json. What are you trying to do with a separate soap client for dev puproses?

Comment: @Jorg, I tried a buch of differend options in the compiler, without success. Currently I have it like this:
`"compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "es2015",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowJs": true,
        ...
    },`
I'm trying to use the soap client for invoking multiple soap webservice operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the npm package `soap` is for Node.js and does not work in a browser. The `http` package is a standard Node.js package.

I think the package `easy-soap-request` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-soap-request) might fit your need. I have no experience with this package though, but the readme provides an example from the browser.

Comment: Is there any way to use standard node packages in UI5 (typescript)?

Comment: Node packages cannot be used in a regular browser. You can use Node packages in an Electron app, but that requires installing an application on the client PC.

Are you trying to integrate your UI5 application with an SAP system? Because if so, it is way easier to create OData Gateway services in the SAP system for your needs instead of using SOAP. UI5 supports OData Gateway services out of the box.